# MySQL error #1415: Failing to return value from table column

Tags: mysql

The following attempt to create a UDF which will find first value of a certain column and return it gives me error:

## 1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a function

What am I doing wrong? Here is the SQL:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getAppointment_DOB
(   
    _hsp integer,
    _year integer,
    _month integer,
    _day integer,
    _slot integer
)
RETURNS datetime 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    declare _answer datetime;

SELECT _answer = DOB 
FROM `appointment`  
where FK_HSP_ID = _hsp and (year(Start_Date)  _year and 
    MONTH(Start_Date) = _month 
    and Day(Start_Date) = _day and K_Time_Slot_ID=_slot) limit 1,1;

RETURN _answer;
END;
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `year(Start_Date)  _year` u missed `=`

Answer (score -1):

You have missed = symbol in where condition

> It doesn't set the variable _answer , it returns a set with a column
>   named _answer

Try use `INTO` statement for your selects.

You want

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION getAppointment_DOB
(   
    _hsp integer,
    _year integer,
    _month integer,
    _day integer,
    _slot integer
)
RETURNS datetime 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    declare _answer datetime;

    SELECT DOB into _answer FROM `appointment`  where FK_HSP_ID = _hsp and (year(Start_Date) = _year and MONTH(Start_Date) = _month and Day(Start_Date) = _day and K_Time_Slot_ID=_slot) limit 1,1;

    RETURN _answer;
END;
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

Take a look at this [Document](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)